# Get column value of row with condition based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I keep writing code like this, when I want a specific column in a row, where I select the row first based on another column.

```
my_col = "Value I am looking for"
df.loc[df["Primary Key"] == "blablablublablablalblalblallaaaabblablalblabla"].iloc[0][
    my_col
]
```

I don't know why, but it seems weird. Is there a more beautiful solution to this?

Comment: Does the primary key column contains unique values?

Comment: Yes, but it's not in index yet. Should I make it index?

Comment: Yes, make it an index then you can use `loc` to access the values easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful with a complete minimally working example, since it is not clear what your data structure looks like. You could use the example given [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]],
     index=['cobra', 'viper', 'sidewinder'],
     columns=['max_speed', 'shield'])
```

If you are then trying to e.g. select the `viper`-row based on its `max_speed`, and then obtain its `shield`-value like so:

```
my_col = "shield"
df.loc[df["max_speed"] == 4].iloc[0][my_col]
```

then I guess that is the way to do that - not a lot of fat in that command.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping I could get rid of .iloc[0] somehow, but as long as it is not index, I guess there is no way.